# How to convert 2014-05-05T09:14:52.150Z string to get current system time

Tags: java

I have a string 2014-05-05T09:14:52.150Z received from server.
I have to convert it to get the current system time 
How can i do that any suggestions.
What the 'T' and 'Z' in the date string signifies.

Comment: The 'T' is just a separator, the 'Z' indicates UTC time zone. Have a look at SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: This is standard http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 date time format.  I would use the Java 8 `ZonedDateTime.parse("2014-05-05T09:14:52.150Z")`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Answer (score 1):

This is XML Schema dateTime format http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp you can parse it like this

```
Date date = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(str)
.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just need to get rid of the 'T' and 'Z' charachters you can use

```
String serverString = "2014-05-05T09:14:52.150Z";
serverString = serverString.replaceAll("T", "");
serverString = serverString.replaceAll("Z", "");
```

Check the String Java API.

Comment: From what I gathered in the question he needs to operate on the string  externally from the server. You are right on the "not changed" part though, my bad.

Comment: Still not clear on how removing those letters helps.

Comment: How will you separate the days from the hours if you remove the T?  How will you deal with the timezone correctly if you remove the Z?  How will you actually make this into a Date (or Calendar, or any instance of any other date-like class) using just the String API?